# Date from MongoDB prints as "date":"2011-05-12T13:51:33Z"

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Why am I getting the "T" and "Z" in the date when I fetch it from MongoDB and convert it to JSON using Rails3?

```
"date":"2011-05-12T13:51:33Z"
```

Thanks

Fetch:

```
@bs = coll.find("headers.from" => email, "date" => {"$gte" => initial_date, "$lte" => Time.now.utc})
```

Insert:

```
date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

Comment: Looks like an ISO8601 formatted date. What does your insert and fetch code look like?

Comment: @Douglas updated with that information.

Answer (score 3):

It's an ISO8601 formatted datetime. The 'T' separates the date from the time and the 'Z' indicates that the date is UTC (GMT). MongoDB doesn't support a Date (only) type, instead everything is converted to a timestamp.

You can drop into the mongo console and run a query you'll see date (and time) fields are stored as ISODate("2011-05-12T13:51:33Z").

Comment: So there is no problem if I convert that .to_json ? When I'm reading the .JSON file, will the date be right? Thanks

Comment: Mongo is automatically in a form of JSON called BSON, what you're looking at on the console of Mongo is, effectively, JSON so converting it to JSON in your ruby app will be fine. One thing you need to remember is that the date you have there is UTC, so you'll need to convert to local time somewhere in your app.